# How do I modify file/directory permissions that is inside of a docker container?

Tags: docker

I installed the eclipse-mosquitto docker container and modified mosquittos config file to use ssl certs.  However mosquitto quits which causes the docker container to shutdown and now refuses to start.  Normally in portainer I can access the console of the container, but I can't access the console due to the container being shutdown.

The file/folder permissions of the ssl certs is what is causing mosquitto to stop.  How can I access the container to change file/folder permissions when it is shutdown?

Comment: If the certificates are being bind-mounted from the host, they will keep the (numeric) owner and permissions they have there, and running `chown` or `chmod` from the host will affect what's visible inside the container.  Do you have more details on what's going wrong, perhaps a [mcve] with any relevant source and the error log from the application?

Comment: I have a lot to learn about volumes and the different types. I ended up redoing the doc ker container with correct permissions. It is now working as expected